# MongoDB: How to update document fields based on document field calculations?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

I'm wondering how I can perform calculations on document fields, and then update an existing field in that document based on those calculations?

I'm currently using a roundabout way of doing it (below), but I'm wondering if there's a more performant or straight-forward way?

Or if possible, have a document field ("cumulativeField") that is dynamic and updates in the following way:

```
db.collection
    .aggregate([
        { $match: { arrayField: { $exists: true } } },
        { $addFields: { cumulativeField: { $sum: "$arrayField.number" } } }
        ])
    .forEach(function (x){
        db.collection.updateOne(
          { id: x.id },
          { $set: { cumulativeField: NumberInt(x.cumulativeField) } }
        )})
```

Note:  arrayField = an "array of objects" field, with each object in the array having a key "number" whose value(s) I am summing up to then put as a single value into the "cumulativeField" field.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB >= 4.2 supports [pipeline updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), and updates can be like aggregation, aggregation result is the new value of the document.

In you case i think you only need to write the code as

```js
updateOne({},
[{ $match: { arrayField: { $exists: true } } },
 { $addFields: { cumulativeField: { $toInt: { $sum: "$arrayField.number" } } } }])
```

Comment: This is great to know!  I'm going to try this out as soon as I can, thanks.